# Turns off gps for my app programatically, still keeping it available for use by other apps

Tags: android, gps, android-location

My application uses location services. I want to turn gps off for my app programatically, keeping it still available for use by other apps.

I tried the following,

locationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener); (implements LocationListener)

locationManager = null;

But it's not seems quite working for me. Any other suggestions??

Comment: Hmm, why do you want to do it? Maybe you think you want it, but it is not really necessary, and not a good idea at all?

Comment: it drains so much of battery. @AlexanderZhak

Comment: In Android 4.0+ you can't turn GPS module on/off. All you can do is to stop receiving and processing GPS data.

Comment: Oh, i see. So how can i stop receiving and processing GPS data ?

Comment: You cannot turn gps on or off programatically prior to android 4.3.It will give securityexception.

Comment: But what about atleast disabling it for my app only??